# Parse background job add multiple record causing error

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am getting strange error.

Failed with: Error: Can't call success/error multiple times
    at updateJobMessageAndReturn (:790:5)
    at Object.success (:826:9)
Here is my code.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("jobAddTags", function(request, status) {
var array=request.params.tagArray;

 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    query = new Parse.Query("Tags");
    query.limit(1);
    query.find({
      success: function(object) {
      if (object) {
        //update
        object.increment("count");
        object.save();
      } else {
        console.log("Add New");
        var tag = Parse.Object.extend("Tags");
        var activity = new Activity();
        tag.set("tag",request.object.get("tag"));
        tag.save();
      }//end else
    }, //end success
  error: function(error) {
    status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong." + error.code + ": " + error.message);
  }//end find
});
status.success("Done Adding Tags");
```

}//end for
});//end job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your status.success down so it is outside the for loop:

```
      ...
      error: function(error) {
        status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong." + error.code + ": " + error.message);
      }//end find
    });

  }//end for
  status.success("Done Adding Tags");
});//end job
```